# Does directory mtime always change when a new file is created inside?

Tags: linux, unix, mtime

Is it always true that when a new file is created in a directory - the directory's mtime changes?

Comment: This is quite easy to test...

Comment: Easy. However, not on all OSes & filesystems at once :)

Answer (score 20):

The short answer is **yes, it should**. A longer answer follows.

A directory is a special kind of file; its contents is a set of *(filename, i-node)* tuples. Thus directory's mtime is updated whenever a tuple is added, removed or changed - that is, a file of any type (including hard links and directories) is added, removed or renamed in the directory (but not in nested directories - those are different "files").

Please note when file's metadata changes (owner, group, mode, atime, ctime, mtime - hosted in *i-node*), *mtime* is NOT updated (neither on the file nor containing dir) but the file's *ctime* does.

See also *Base Definitions volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001, [Section 4.7, File Times Update](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_07)*.

Comment: Note, that this is only true for files that are created (etc) directly inside of the parent directory in question, but not for files created (etc) in a directory under the parent directory. Perhaps this is obvious to others, but it wasn't to me (I had to test to find the answer).

Comment: @logidelic thanks, I've updated the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Why does the directory's ctime also change when you create a new file in it?

Comment: @Mr.Roland Because ctime changes whenever any status changes, and mtime is one of the statuses. So mtime change causes ctime change.